# Dashboard Widget drawn before opening HTML tag

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I am making my first dashboard widget and it is displaying successfully but the output HTML from the function below is showing up before the opening HTML tag on dashboard page.

The code involved is below.  Do I need some init call prior to the add_action() call?

```
function example_add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget(
                 'donationsmtcarmel',         // Widget slug.
                 'Mt. Carmel Donations',         // Title.
                 'draw_widget' // Display function.
        );  
 }
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'draw_widget' );


function draw_widget() {
    $dObj = new Donation;
    $donations = $dObj->retrieve("`paypal_txn` != '' AND `archived` = '0' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    echo '
      <div id="normal-sortables-20" class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable"><div id="donations_postbox" class="postbox" style="margin-top:12px">
        <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br></div><h3 class="hndle"><span style="padding-left:12px">Mt. Carmel Donations</span></h3>
          <div class="inside">
            <div class="table table_content" style="padding-left:12px">';
     echo "<p><strong>Recent Donations:</strong></p><p style='padding-left:12px'>";
     if ($donations) { 
        foreach ($donations as $d) {
            echo $d->donor_name.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$'.$d->tx()->mc_gross.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.date('n/j/Y g:i A', strtotime($d->date))."<br/>\n";
        }
     } else {
         echo 'None.';
     }

     echo '   </p>
              <p><a href="http://www.foo.org/wp-admin/index.php?page=donations">Donations Page</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      ';

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add_action` should call the function that registers the dashboard widget, which then in turn calls the function to render the widget. Right now you have the `add_action` calling the function to render the widget directly.

change:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'draw_widget' );
```

to:

```
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'example_add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

Comment: Thank you!  Feel foolish since wp_dashboard_setup() is so self-explanatory.  Much obliged!